# File format for Python project data

Tags: python, user-data

I am in the process of writing a Python application. Now I want to allow the user to save his or her project data to a file. Now I am stuck with a design decision, what is the best format to save data in Python?

As far as I know, the built-in alternatives are JSON and XML, from which XML is known to never be the answer, not even the question. I would like to have an easy to use format with easy backwards compatibility if I'd add more data to the file later on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean like Pickle?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go with JSON. Its the way the shore, store and manipulate any form of user data these days. Its cross platform and without the extra overhead which comes with using XML. JSON is also programmer friendly as you don't have to entirely parse the suer data as you would have to if you use XML.

Comment: But if he's using python why use a different format like JSON? Why not use python's own pickle? What's to gain from using JSON?

Comment: To make the user data cross platform accessible and to future proof the application. It is highly unlikely that the user data he would be getting through his application would be for his own use and would not require sharing with other stakeholders.

Comment: It seems to me that cross platform accessibility is not a requirment here, and that he's looking for a native python solution

Comment: With JSON you have possibly the need to serialize and deserialize your own data types. Pickle is more flexible here.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is python data, a good way to easily store and access it is using python's own library called pickle. Unless you need to pass the data to other platforms, it's better than using JSON. And it's very easy to use as well, like so:

```
import pickle

mydata = {'1': 'hello', '2': 'world'}
output = open('data.pkl', 'wb')

pickle.dump(data, output)
output.close()
```

When re-opening the file, you do this:

```
pkl = open('data.pkl', 'rb')
data = pickle.load(pkl)
```

Of course, if that's all you do with it, it's better to use CPickle, which behaves the same but is tremendously faster (because it is implemented in C). The downside for CPickle is being less flexible. For more about Pickle you should [check out pydocs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-pickle)

Comment: There are more downsides of pickle. It's not human readable, and it results in arbitrary code execution vulnerabilities with malicously constructed data (a concern if users share project data with each other). It also arguably violates the law of least power, because for things like project metadata you don't need to serialize arbitrary objects, the JSON model is sufficient.

Comment: I agree with most of your points, but I think it's also very dependant of the project. human-readability doesn't seem to me like an important issue at all. JSON requires more serialization work, and has data format limitations while pickle is very flexible for the python environment. So yeah, really depends on the project